# value is neither an array nor a pointer

Tags: c, arrays

I have this code:

```
int ID [STUDENTS];
int Scores [STUDENTS][GRADES];
int Hi [GRADES];
int Lo [GRADES];
double Avg [GRADES];
int numStudents;

/*getData function called*/
int getData(ID, Scores,  numStudents)
{
  int student_count;
  int quiz_count;

  FILE* spIn;


  spIn = fopen("myfile.dat", "r");
  student_count=0;
  while (fscanf (spIn, "%d", ID[student_count]) != EOF)
  {
     for (quiz_count = 0; quiz_count < GRADES; quiz_count++)
     {
        fscanf (spIn, "%d", Scores[student_count][quiz_count]);
     }
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error in title for the lines: `while(fscanf (spIn, "%d", ID[student_count]) !=EOF)` and `fscanf (spIn, "%d", Scores[student_count][quiz_count]);`

Please help I don't know what to do!

Comment: `int getData(ID, Scores,  numStudents)` - it would seem something is amiss in that declaration. Either formalize those parameters with proper types or toss them outright and (ugh) use your globals.

Comment: in the line inside the for loop, you're trying to scan into an integer, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of variables `ID` and `Scores`. Both variables are defined in two places -

- As a global variable at the top of the file, and
- As a named parameter to your function.

The named parameter is closer in scope to the place of use, hence it wins.

It looks like the use in the second place (i.e. as function parameter) is not intentional, because the declarations lack types<sup>*</sup>. Removing them will make your code compile.

<sup>*</sup> in which case C considers them `int`s, and issues a warning which should have explained the error to you: since the compiler thinks that the inner-scope `ID` and `Score` are `int`s, you cannot use index operator `[]` with them.

Answer (score 2):

Both instances of fscanf() are incorrect. fscanf() needs pointers, not ints, to modify the memory at that location.

Your first call is this:

```
while (fscanf (spIn, "%d", ID[student_count]) != EOF)
```

When you index the variable `ID` you're passing the value of the `student_count` index to the function. Which fscanf() tries to interpret as a memory location(Not good)!

This:

```
while (fscanf (spIn, "%d", &ID[student_count]) != EOF)
```

passes the reference of the array at index `student_count` to fscanf().

The same is true of the other call to fscanf()!